# Fiddler issue logging requests

Tags: fiddler

I think I must have changed a setting somewhere, but fiddler if only logging my gmail notifier and rad.msn.com requests.

Any other requests (going to bbc.co.uk for example) are not logged?

Any suggestions on what I can do to get these back?

I have ensured that Tools -> Fiddler Options -> [Connections Tab] -> Monitor all connections is checked.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a filter set; look at the status bar at the bottom of the window.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp#MissingTraffic